# How to create a unit test to check the response of an API made in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to test a JSON API I implemented in Flask

Here's my view function

```
@app.route("/dummy")
def dummy(): 
    return {"dummy":"dummy-value"}
```

And in my Unittest I'm testing using

```
def setUp(self):
    self.app = my_app.app.test_client()

def test_dummy(self):
     response = self.app.get("/dummy")
     self.assertEqual(response['dummy'], "dummy-value")
```

However, when I ran it, I get the error `TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using `jsonify()` fixes the error `'dict' object is not callable`

```
from flask import jsonify
@app.route("/dummy")
def dummy(): 
    return jsonify({"dummy":"dummy-value"})
```

And for the test, you'll have to pull the JSON out of the HTTP response

```
import json

class MyAppCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        my_app.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app = my_app.app.test_client()

    def test_dummy(self):
        response = self.app.get("/dummy")
        data = json.loads(response.get_data(as_text=True))

        self.assertEqual(data['dummy'], "dummy-value")
```

This now runs for me.

Comment: in mine the `app` does not have a get attribute, how do I do a test response in unittest, 
this is my project structure

`
├───.idea
│   └───inspectionProfiles
├───project
│   └───__pycache__
└───tests

`

Answer (score -3):

You should return a string, not a dictionary object!

```
@app.route("/dummy")
def dummy(): 
    return flask.jsonify(dummy="dummy-value")
```

And in your test, parse the JSON using `json.loads(..)` and then assert.

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment?

Comment: Not positive, but potentially got downvoted as returning a `dict` is very common

Comment: "You should return a string, not a dictionary object!" - Not a helpful response. No reasoning/explanation given. Returning a dict is common practice